# Customize facebook send dialog

Tags: facebook, dialog, message, send, friend

I need to send message to my facebooks friends which should include:
- picture
- url
- my custom message
and I need to know to whom this message was sent.

Functionality is similar to Spotify.com (share song between friends)

Please advise how this can be done

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Facebook Send Dialog (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/) to send messages, though you don't receive the friend IDs back.